# What is the correct construction for 'as was my hunch'

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I want to say

> 'X team did not win and that was my hunch.

I want to write this expression in the form of **as I said, as I expected**,

> 1 : **As was my hunch**, X team did not win.
>
> 2: **As my hunch was**, X team did not win.

Which of these expressions is correct? If neither, then what would be correct construct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the two choices you provide, I'd go with the first; *As my hunch was* reads as an incomplete sentence, while *As was my hunch* at least does make it clear that you are about to say something that happened that was in line with your expectation.

In general, however, I would say that neither of the choices given is very natural; the most common construction that mentions "hunch" would be

> I had a hunch that they were going to lose.

Comment: How about *Hugo's overuse of description in the novel was unfortunate, as was my hunch.*?  --Quasimoto

Answer (score 2):

You can have a hunch that someone will win, but someone cannot win as 'hunched'.

Hunch, in this sense, only works as a noun. To force the word hunch in the way you wish to use it will sound strained. The best I can do would be:

> my hunch was right, X team did not win.

But I rather prefer:

> X team lost, as I had predicted.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, both of those phrases are uncommon. Common alternatives are:

> As expected, their team did not win.
>
> As I had expected, their team did not win.
>
> My hunch was right; their team did not win.